# Numpy negated indexing like python's not

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I need some help here, as I, unfortunately, could not find a solution myself.
I have an array (image) in numpy where I indexed the center part and could create an image, where exactly that center part was set to black like this:

```
11111
10001
10001
10001
11111
```

Which could be accomplished by something like `img[1:3, 1:3] = 0`.
Now I also want the complement of this like:

```
00000
01110
01110
01110
00000
```

Is there anything like `img[~1:3,~1:3] = 0` in numpy?

I have tried to find related questions, but could not think of more searchwords and no one seems to have the same problem. Maybe the solution is too easy? I was hoping for a *non-hacky* solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *basic slicing* doesn't allow "all indices except those specified". In NumPy you generally solve this using [masks (also called "boolean array indexing")](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). For example:

```
>>> mask = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=bool)
>>> mask[1:4, 1:4] = True
>>> mask
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then use the mask for slicing:

```
>>> img = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int)
>>> img[mask] = 0
>>> img
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But this time the mask can be inverted with `~`:

```
>>> img = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int)
>>> img[~mask] = 0
>>> img
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Not sure about the down- but got you an upvote as this directly solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of row and column masks and then use broadcasted `OR-ing` between the two masks -

```
def assign_not_block(a, row_start, row_stop, col_start, col_stop, value=0):
    m,n = a.shape   
    row_mask = np.ones(m,dtype=bool)
    col_mask = np.ones(n,dtype=bool)
    row_mask[row_start: row_stop] = 0
    col_mask[col_start: col_stop] = 0
    a[row_mask[:,None] | col_mask] = value
    return a
```

Sample run -

```
In [244]: a
Out[244]: 
array([[5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 2],
       [4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 2],
       [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 6, 5],
       [5, 6, 6, 7, 0, 2, 1]])

In [245]: assign_not_block(a, row_start=1, row_stop=4, col_start=1, col_stop = 5)
Out[245]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 7, 8, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 6, 4, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 1, 8, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: You can also use `-1` as stops to exclude the last row/column.

Comment: @MSeifert Keeping it generic, as OP hasn't mentioned keeping last row or column.

Comment: I meant as arguments for the function in your last example. :)

Comment: Thanks this is an interesting approach, but I stayed with @MSeifert s solution as it is (in my opinion) simpler.